# How to make subplots of Wind Roses?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create a figure with two wind roses side by side, but it keeps returning me `KeyError: 'theta_labels'` at line 18.

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import windrose

#### ---------------- 

def set_legend(ax):
    l = ax.legend(loc="center right",borderaxespad=-1)
    # l.get_frame().set_fill(False) #transparent legend
    plt.setp(l.get_texts(), fontsize=10,weight='bold')

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
left_rectangle = [0, 0.1, 0.4, 0.75] #[left, bottom, width, height] as a fraction of total figure size
right_rectangle = [0.5, 0.1, 0.4, 0.75] #[left, bottom, width, height] as a fraction of total figure size
ax1 = WindroseAxes(fig, left_rectangle)
ax2 = WindroseAxes(fig, right_rectangle)


fig.add_axes(ax1)
ax1.bar(DIRECTIONDATA1,DATA1, normed=True, opening=0.6, bins = np.arange(0, 6, 1),edgecolor='grey', nsector=8, cmap=cm.viridis_r)
ax1.grid(True,linewidth=1.5,linestyle='dotted')
set_legend(ax1)


fig.add_axes(ax2)
ax2.bar(np.array(DIRECTIONDATA2),np.array(DATA2), normed=True, opening=0.6, bins = np.arange(0, 6, 1),edgecolor='grey', nsector=8, cmap=cm.viridis_r)
ax2.grid(True,linewidth=1.5,linestyle='dotted')
set_legend(ax2)
```

I am using the following Wind Rose: https://github.com/python-windrose/windrose/tree/master/windrose

Comment: Apart from the undefined data and library imports, your code seems to run OK. The error is probably related to how the data are defined, or that some data have illegal values. (For example, negative heights would be weird to draw on a polar grid)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot do add a data sample to the code I posted here. In the end I manage to run it on another PC (without changing anything from the code and using the same data), but still have no clue why is this happening on mine.